# How to not only optically rescale an Image in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, image, core-image

I found this method for rescaling an Image:

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage: (UIImage*) sourceImage scaledToWidth: (float) i_width
{
float oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width;

 float scaleFactor = i_width / oldWidth;

float newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor;
float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
[sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

Now my question is: If i scale the `UIImage` (a big one) down to maybe 50x50  pixels (which I presume is the unit of "height" and "width", right?) and then scale the `UIImage` up again, will the `UIImage` be pixelated (which is what i want)? Meaning will the `UIImage` only look smaller, or will it actually be 50x50 pixels?

Comment: As far as i know ,once you down the size  you can't increase it.IT will be pixelated.

Comment: If you want to do that just stick the image in an image view and make that do the scaling.

Comment: Before posting such a question, try it first. Much faster than posting a question and waiting for a response. If, after trying it, it doesn't do what you need, then post your question with relevant details.